# Java 2D array: How to fill elements in order

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array `int[][] arr = new int[a][a];`

I want to use following regulation to fill half of the matrix

The formula can be simplified as

`a[i][j]=input` (where i=j)

`a[i][j]=a[i-1][j+1]` (where i!=j)

So only half of the matrix is needed.

Currently I have done the first loop but have no idea how to make it iterative to proceed

Here is what I have done:

```
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j < a[i].length;j++){
        if(i==j){
            a[i][j]=keyboard.nextInt();;
        }
    }             
}
```

Now this can only fill the first set as this

[image]

I am stuck in proceeding the loop to compute elements to achieve this

[image]

and then

[image]

finally,

[image]

I believe the crucial part is set index.

Comment: Is `i` your columns and `j` the rows? Also, you have some contradicting information, you say "where `i != j`" and "So only half of the matrix is needed", but if you're filling all things where `i == j`` and `i != j` the entire matrix *is* needed.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` in the value you want to fill in the upper half:

```
for (i = 0; i < a; ++i)
    for(j = 0; j < a; ++j)
        if(i <= j)
            arr[i][j] = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill a 2D array in that sequence with a code like this:

```js
var arr = [];

// Add 3 zero-filled arrays with different lengths
arr.push(new Array(4+1).join('0').split('').map(parseFloat));
arr.push(new Array(8+1).join('0').split('').map(parseFloat));
arr.push(new Array(6+1).join('0').split('').map(parseFloat));

k = 1;
stillFilling = true; j = 0;
while(stillFilling){

    stillFilling = false;   
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if ((i+j)<arr[i].length){
            arr[i][(i+j)]=k; // here you assign the value.
            stillFilling = true;
            k++;
        } 
    }
    j++; 
}
```

See it on action in JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/fcz8ts6d/14/

Answer (score 0):

```
char[][] m = new char[7][7];
    for(int i=0; i<m.length; i++) {
        for(int j=i; j<m.length; j++) {
            m[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<m.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<m.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```